# series 1/n! = 1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have this series:

$\frac{1}{2!} + \frac{2}{3!} +\frac{3}{4!} + ... + \frac{n-1}{n!} = 1$

How can I prove that? We know that we can use $\frac{n-1}{n!} = \frac{1}{n!} - \frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ to cancel terms, but at the end I am left with $1-\frac{1}{n+1}$, what did I do wrong?

Comment: I think you wanted to write $2/3!$ and $3/4!$ and the series should be infinite.

Comment: Absolutely! Thank you

Comment: The *finite* sum is equal to $1-\frac{1}{n!}$. To sum the *infinite* series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{n-1}{n!}$, let $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Also note $\frac{n-1}{n!}=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}-\frac{1}{n!}$.